# Guardar varios registros en sequelize con postgres

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, sequelize.js

Al crear dos registros en **sequelize** me devuelve un array con un objeto, fucionado en nodejs.

Datos enviados desde potsman:
Se envían un array con dos objetos en esta estructura

```
let arrayObj = [
  {
    certification_type: req.body.certification_type,
    certification_ruc: req.body.certification_ruc,
  }
];
```

respuesta desde el servidor

```
{

        "certification_type": [
            "Construccion",
            "Industrial"
        ],
        "certification_ruc": [
            "Buena",
            "Exelente"
        ],

    }
```

Necesito que me lleguén así:

```
[{

      certification_type: "Construccion",
      certification_ruc: "Buena",

   },
   {

      certification_type: "Industria",
      certification_ruc: "Excelente",

}]
```